# How to set right strides in MLMultiArray in Core ML? What's the strides' values' meaning?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, deep-learning, coreml, stride

How to set right `strides` in `MLMultiArray` in Core ML? What's the EVERY `strides`' values' meaning?

For example, assume a Core ML model input `shape` is `(1, 3, 1280, 720)`, so how to set `strides` when create `MLMultiArray` object by using `initWithDataPointer:shape:dataType:strides:deallocator:error:`?

I set `strides` as `(720 * 1280, 720 * 1280, 720, 1)` from some websites, but I don't know why set as this, or if it's right. What's the connection between `shape` and `strides`. No more documentation about it on Apple Developer website.

Comment: It looks like you are using a RGB image. Why not use the image type instead of multi-array?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock For some reason cannot use image type, just can use `MLMultiArray`.

Comment: You can create separated model with PyTorch or TF, then convert to coremltools to CoreML.
Which can just convert from MLMultiArray to Image.

Like in my article: https://medium.com/p/df93de9d2d46